# Sphinx creates empty documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm trying to understand how to make Sphinx work.

I'm not Python developer - instead, I want to use reST and Sphinx for general purpose texts.

So, I have Python, DocUtils and Sphinx installed. I have `test.rst` inside `C:\Test\` directory. Then, I launch `cmd.exe` in this directory and type: `sphinx-quickstart`. Then, I press Enter multiple times for default presets.

Then I have some new files in this folder, including `make.bat`. Then, I run: `make.bat html`. Then, the Sphinx HTML files are created. But when I open `index.html` - I don't see the contents of my original `test.rst`.

So, how to make it work?

(Despite the completely identical title, my question is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333190/sphinx-generates-empty-documentation) in any sense).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add `test` to the `toctree` directive in your `index.rst`.

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 2

    test
```

See the documentation of [Directives](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree) for additional options and syntax.